# com.android.support:appcompat searches in wrong place

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm trying to link espresso to the project

Here's error I get

```
_MyProject:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0_

_> Could not find org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1._
```

Searched in the following locations:

**C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.1/hamcrest-library-1.1.jar_**

And cant find another libraries that are needed to compile Espresso

Actual Espresso library is here, but gradle can't see it

**C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\test\espresso**

build.gradle file consists of:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()       // This is the default repo
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
        compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
        provided fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'ext_libs')
        compile project(':third_party:facebook')

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral();
}
```

to your `build.gradle` at the top level (i.e., as a peer of your `android` and `dependencies` closures).

For example, in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Testing/JUnit4) that uses JUnit4 (though not Espresso), I have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // required for testing-support-lib dependencies
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        testApplicationId "com.commonsware.android.gradle.hello.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt' // required for no good reason...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the top level build.gradle.

Project was moved from Ant to Gradle, so I dont have top lvl build + app/build.

MavenCentral as default repo causes same error

Comment: @DmitryGr: Yes, but you do not have a `repositories` closure, listing a site like `mavenCentral()`, as a peer of the `dependencies` closure where you are pulling in `testing-support-lib`. You will see that in my `build.gradle` file (which also happens to be set up for a project without modules, as is yours).

Comment: I'm new in android studio and still dont understand how, but your solution works! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Added repository closure as was advised by **CommonsWare**. Builds fine now.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // required for testing-support-lib dependencies
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue and solved by adding below line to the "< userhome >\.gradle\gradle.properties" file in Windows machine.

```
systemProp.ANDROID_HOME         = C:\\android-sdk-windows
```